# Convertir Fecha y Hora que están en decimal a formato Hora/Fecha PHP

Tags: php

estoy generando una rutina donde se subirá un layout en formato csv a la base de datos, pero tengo un problema, en excel la hora y la fehca están en formato general:
Fecha: 43564
Hola: 0.193056

Si aplico la formula de =TEXTO(A2,"dd/mm/AAAA") lo convierte a 09/04/2019 y para la hora aplico =TEXTO(A3,"hh:mm am/pm") y me da 04:38am

El problema es que el usuario solo cargará el layout y no debe manipular dicho formato, en PHP como puedo hacer esa conversión, ya que las variables las pasa así como decimal.

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel tiene una marca del tiempo propia, además con un problema añadido, en algunas versiones de Excel, la marca del tiempo empieza el  `1 de enero de 1900`, mientras que en otras empieza el `1 de enero de 1904` (ver [*Diferencias entre el sistema de fecha 1900 y 1904 en Excel*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system) en la documentación de Microsoft).

PHP por su parte usa la marca del tiempo Unix, que empieza el `1 de enero de 1970`.

En tu caso, por la fecha resultante se puede deducir que tu Excel está usando la marca del tiempo que empieza el `1 de enero de 1900`, entonces necesitas convertir el valor `43564` + `0.193056` a la marca del tiempo Unix.

Para hacer la conversión puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- restar 70 años en días: `25569`
- multiplicarlo por un día expresado en segundos: `86400`
- obtener la fecha GMT usando la función `gmdate()`

A partir de ahí, para trabajar más cómodo, puedes crear un objeto `DateTime` y si quieres presentar por separado la fecha y la hora aplicas `format` sobre ese objeto.

El código quedaría así:

```
#Estos son los valores de ambas celdas
$excelTS=43564+0.193056;
#Aplicamos la fórmula
$unixDT=($excelTS - 25569) * 86400;
#Convertimos a GMT
$gmtDate= gmdate("d-m-Y H:i:s", $unixDT);
#Creamos un objeto DateTime para trabajr con él
$mDate = new DateTime($gmtDate);
```

Veamos algunos ejemplos de la flexibilidad de trabajar con objetos, porque `format` da posibilidades enormes según lo que necesites, todos estos ejemplos usan el mismo objeto para presentar la información de forma distinta:

```
echo $mDate->format("Y-m-d").PHP_EOL;
echo $mDate->format("H:i:s").PHP_EOL;
echo $mDate->format("g:i a").PHP_EOL;
printf("Semana %d del año %d",$mDate->format("W"),$mDate->format("Y").PHP_EOL);
```

**Salida:**

```
2019-04-09
04:38:00
4:38 am
Semana 15 del año 2019
```

### PD:

1. Si trabajas con bibliotecas como `PHPExcel` (ya obsoleta)  o `PHPSpreadSheets`, dichas bibliotecas tienen sus propios métodos para convertir fechas del forma Excel al formato PHP. Si es así, convendría usar dichas bibliotecas.
2. Si vas a usar mucho este código, podrías crear una función que reciba los valores de las celdas, haga las conversiones y te devuelva un objeto `DateTime` con la fecha creada. Esto te permitirá reutilizar el código incorporándolo o no a una clase utilitaria. Esto facilita las cosas, sobre todo en proyectos grandes.

### Enlaces:

1. [Convert Excel time to Unix time](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-excel-time-to-unix-time)
2. [TimeStamp to Date converter](https://www.dcode.fr/timestamp-converter)

Comment: Linux esta basado en Minix, que a su vez esta basado en Unix; PHP usa marca de tiempo Unix. El formato que usa Excel se le conoce como Clarion Date.

Comment: @Sal tienes razón, gracias por el comentario. He actualizado la respuesta. Además, Excel usa dos marcas del tiempo según la doc de Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Excelente apoyo, funciona perfectamente.

Mi código quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
    function formatearHora($HORA)
    {
        $UNIX_HOUR = ($HORA - 25569) * 86400;
        return gmdate("H:i", $UNIX_HOUR);
    }

    function formatearFecha($FECHA)
    {
        $UNIX_DATE = ($FECHA - 25569) * 86400;
        return gmdate("d-m-Y", $UNIX_DATE);
    }
```